# OpenFileDialog only loads files from the root

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have an C# application to load some files into my database, but when I try to load the file the application only load from one location (C:), but I need to be able to load the files from any location.
I use this function to load the files

```
private void cmdArchivoTotal_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog dialogoArchivo = new OpenFileDialog();

    dialogoArchivo.InitialDirectory =
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
    dialogoArchivo.Filter = "CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv";

    if (dialogoArchivo.ShowDialog().Value)
        txtArchivoTotal.Text =
            System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("\\"+dialogoArchivo.SafeFileName);             
}
```

At first I was thinking this was for run the application in debug mode, but even deployed the application only load the files from "C:\".

How can I load files from any disk and directory?

Answer (score 4):

You're using [`OpenFileDialog.SafeFileName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.safefilename(v=vs.110).aspx), which only returns the filename, not the path. By prepending `\`, you're constricted to reading files from the current disk's root.

Just use the `FileName` property, which contains the full path:

```
 txtArchivoTotal.Text = dialogoArchivo.FileName
```